# Uploaded Video not played in browser in php

Tags: php, video, browser

i am building one website.where i want user to upload there video and play whenever they want.

i am able to upload video. but when i am want to play that or any (other video) also its not playing in browser. i know some where i am going wrong but can not finding the issue.

Here my code for upload video:

```
<form action="video.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<span> Add Video's here</span>
<p>
    <label>Give a caption to the video</label>
    <input type="text"  name="caption" title="caption">
</p>
         <input type="file" name="file" id="files" value="Upload Photo" style="border:0">
        <input type="submit" name="Upload" id="uploadph" value="Upload video">


</form>
```

PHP code video.php:

```
$allowedExts = array("avi","wmv","mp4");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$filename=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filepath=$path.$filename;
echo $filepath; 

if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/x-ms-wmv")
||($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/avi")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
   echo"1";
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
   echo"sdfsd";
    }
  else
    { 
       echo"2";
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/".$filename);
       echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    }
```

It is uploading in `upload` folder. when i want to play this it not playing.

Code to play video:

```
<html>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls="true" scale="aspect"><source src="upload/test.avi" height="100" width="100"></video>

</body>
</html>
```

please can any one help me on this.

thank you.

Comment: check this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159929/how-to-play-all-video-files-in-browser-using-php

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. is there any way to achieve my goal?

Comment: u can,check out my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!-- BEGIN GENERIC ALL BROWSER FRIENDLY HTML FOR WINDOWS MEDIA PLAYER -->

<object id="MediaPlayer1" width="150" height="170"
classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
standby="Loading Microsoft® Windows® Media Player components..."
type="application/x-oleobject" align="middle">
<param name="FileName" value="test.avi">
<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="True">
<param name="DefaultFrame" value="mainFrame">
<param name="autostart" value="false">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2"
pluginspage = "http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"
src="upload/test.avi"
autostart="false"
align="middle"
width="150"
height="170"
defaultframe="rightFrame"
showstatusbar="true">
</embed>
</object>
```

Comment: thank for replay. but here its asking for install window media player.its for user so if user might not install it and he/she can not play the video. is there any way to do it directly so that user can see easily there video?

Comment: sorry i am new to php. can you please tell me how to use flowplayer in above your code?

Comment: i installed window media player even those it is not playing the video.what is the problem?

Comment: In flowplayer, only .mp4, .flv, .mov video supported. please follow link (http://flowplayer.org/designer/) and after click view source and copy code in file.

Comment: hello  Hardik Panseriya. if i add other mp4 videos it giving me error as **Video dimensions won't probably match your player** this error how to handle?

Answer (score 0):

if u get ur video using id means u can use like this

```
<?php
    if(empty($_GET[id]) OR !is_numeric($_GET[id])){
      echo 'Error';
    }else{
      $query=msyql_query("SELECT id,name,file FROM videos WHERE id='" . $_GET[id] . "' LIMIT 1");
      if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){
        echo 'Error.';
      }else{
        $vid=mysql_fetch_object($query);
        $file=$vid->file;
        // put here your html
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: thank for reply.here that uploaded file is not playing. that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can play the video in any browser using the direct link, there's a chance AVI isn't supported by your browser.
http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

You'll want to have multiple video formats to insure a wide coverage, also you might look into using something like: http://mediaelementjs.com/